# how to use websokets in phonegap application for notify user?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, websocket, phonegap-plugins

I need to write phonegap(ios and android) app that in background listen websockets connection and notify user.
Is any plugin for that, exist? Or any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the network stack (and therefore WebSocket connectivity) is interrupted when an application goes into the background.  I think all you really have time to do is register an APNS / GCM handler when the OS tells you to suspend your application.

You might want to ask this question on the [Kaazing Website](https://kaazing.com/support/) (there are a few folks there who know this stuff) to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket adds basic web sockets functionality to phone gap on android. In addition, you can use also [socket.io](http://socket.io) if you want a more elaborate javascript API that what vanilla web sockets provide.